# Php Regular Expression /^\d{10}$/;

Tags: javascript, regex

Am trying to update a PHP script which has this code:

```
function CheckNumber(MyNumber)
{
    var MN = /^\d{10}$/;
    if (MN.test(MyNumber)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think the script above force entry of 10 digits. nothing less and nothing more.

I need to fix it with the condition
- not more than 12 digits
- also allows less than 12 digits. 
- no special characters.

Please help. I don't understand regular expression codings.

Comment: How many characters is the minimum?

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:php] but the posted code is, probably, [tag:javascript]. Please use the correct tag(s).

Comment: this is javascript, not php

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info – start to learn some basics then.

Answer (score 4):

The `{` and `}` characters identify repetition. `{10}` means *exactly* 10. You can change this to have a minimum and maximum.

Minimum 5, maximum 12:
`{5,12}`

No minimum, maximum 12:
`{,12}`

You can do it the other way round too, so a set minimum with no maximum.

Minimum 5, no maximum:
`{5,}`

Comment: it works! thanks for the help and also tagging "javascript" to my post. sorry about that.

Comment: @Stewiek you should mark the answer if it was what you were looking for.  To me, it looks like Leonard gave you an excellent explanation and answer to your question.  Thanks